# Attribute Error - Model object has no attribute 'COOKIES'

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was initially having issues getting data from my API and it gave a "Forbidden" error, and now that I have fixed that with cookies and csrf token it's not working anymore.

The Error:

> ```
> cookie_token = request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME]
> AttributeError: 'networthChart' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'
> [30/Jan/2021] "GET /api/networthchart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 102936
> ```

I am trying to data from an endpoint and this error comes up.
here is the code:

JS:

```
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    
    
    const request = new Request(
        "/api/networthchart/data/",
        {headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}}
    );
    
    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/networthchart/data/'
      var defaultData = []
      var labels = []
      
      $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
          labels = data.labels
          defaultData = data.default
          var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: {
                  labels: labels,
                  datasets: [{
                      label: '# of Votes',
                      data: defaultData,
                             .......
</script>
```

The view:

```
class networthChart(APIView, View):  
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    @ensure_csrf_cookie
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("its working")
        labels = ["Red","Green"]
        default_items = [8,10]

        if not self.request.user.is_active:
           return HttpResponseForbidden("Not signed in") # any error you want to display       
        
        data = {
            "labels" : labels,
            "default" : default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decorating a method (a function that belongs to a class). The decorators normally are used to decorate function based views, to decorate a method you need to use the `method_decorator`. The problem is that a method's first argument is always the instance of the class, while the decorator is assuming it to be the request instance. Try this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
def get(self, request, format=None):
```

Comment: thanks, I think its working now, btw, you seem experienced with this do you know what might be causing the following error: Forbidden: /api/networthchart/data/

Comment: @VardhanMahajan have a look at this link [Permissions - Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)